# Interruzione di fornitura di corrente elettrica: come si esprime nel linguaggio comune?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request

Nel linguaggio comune, come si esprime un'interruzione di fornitura di corrente elettrica? Per esempio, come potrei completare questa frase per esprimere che la causa del non funzionamento del router è l'interruzione di  fornitura della corrente elettrica?

> Non abbiamo connessione a Internet: il router non funziona perché   _________________.

Comment: Non so se _somministrazione_ è accettabile in questo contesto, ma _fornitura_ è il termine equivalente più usato nel linguaggio burocratico. Si somministra una medicina, e, in burocratese, anche un test, per esempio.

Comment: @WalterTross: Ho trovato questo vocabolo nei testi dei contratti di alcune compagnie di energia elettrica,  ma forse si tratta di un termine molto burocratico.

Comment: Comunque, adesso modifico il testo della domanda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per dire che la luce è andata via per colpa di disguidi tecnici imprevisit si usa: "è andata via la luce" oppure "è saltata la luce". Se è un'operazione in corso per lavori si usa "hanno tagliato la corrente", se invece è permanente per questioni di mancati pagamenti o trasferimenti di abitazione si usa "mi hanno staccato la luce/corrente".

Answer (score 4):

Dipende dal contesto:

- Il router non funziona perché *manca l'energia elettrica* (ad esempio a causa di un temporale).
- Il router non funziona perché *non siamo allacciati alla rete elettrica* (in caso di trasloco o di una casa nuova ad esempio).
- Il router non funziona perché *hanno sospeso la fornitura di energia elettrica* (per non avere pagato la bolletta ad esempio).

Comment: Anche "perché hanno tolto la luce/corrente", "perché siamo senza luce/corrente", "perché è andata via la luce/corrente" (l'ultimo non mi piace molto, però si dice).

Comment: Si, dipende dal livello colloquiale a cui l'OP si riferisce. "E'andata via la luce" e' forse la frase più comune!!

Comment: Sono d'accordo sulla diffusione di “è andata via la luce” nel parlato, ma per esempio non lo scriverei in un avviso.

Comment: Ed "è saltata la luce"? Dialettale? A me sembra più famigliare di "è andata via la luce". Si parla sempre comunque di stile colloquiale.

Answer (score 2):

Se vuoi dirlo in un linguaggio molto colloquiale devi dire — come suggerisce @karoshi in un commento sotto questa domanda — '... perché è andata via la luce'.

Comment: Si tratta di una "community wiki", dunque, invece di votare negativamente, si dovrebbe usare "Edit" per completare la risposta.

Comment: Questi non sanno neanche cos'è una 'community wiki', @charo. Sono solo coalizzati contro di me.

Comment: Chi sono “questi”, @ElberichSchneider? Quanto a me, non ti ho downvotato nonostante non trovi la risposta particolarmente utile, ma confesso che esternazioni come questo farebbero venire voglia di farlo. Sii costruttivo, non paranoico! :-)